# is any linear function $C^\infty(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a velocity?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ a smooth manifold, $C^\infty(M)$ is space of smooth functions on $M$, $\gamma$ is a curve $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M$, and $\gamma(\lambda_0)=p\in M$. Define the ***velocity*** of $\gamma$ at $p$ is the linear map $v_{\gamma,p}:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
$$v_{\gamma,p}(f):=(f\circ \gamma)'(\lambda_0)$$

Is any linear function $C^\infty(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a velocity? i.e. for an arbitrary linear function $\phi:C^\infty(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we can find a velocity $v_{\gamma,p}$ such that $\phi=v_{\gamma,p}$. If not, give an example.

Comment: Your terminology is not too good. The velocity is actually the tangent vector $\gamma'(\lambda_0)$. What you're defining is a directional derivative rather than a velocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. The thing that makes "velocity vectors" (usually called tangent vectors or derivations at $p$) unique in comparision to any linear functional $C^\infty(M)\rightarrow\mathbb R$, is that the product rule is satisfied.
$$v(fg)=f(p)v(g)+g(p)v(f)$$
This could be shown for any $v_{\gamma,p}$ you defined using the regular product rule for derivatives on the real line. And in fact, any linear fuctional satisfying the product rule, must be of the form $v_{\gamma,p}$ for some $\gamma$.

So for instance, $f \mapsto f(p)$ is a linear functional of the required form, but couldn't be a member of $T_p M$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. You would need the Leibniz rule, as well. Here's are a few easy counterexamples. Let $M=\Bbb R$ and $p=0$. Take $\phi(f) = f(0)$ or $\phi(f) = f''(0)$. Or, why not even $\phi(f) = f(1)+f(0)$?